# Creating Alias For List of Arguments in Bash

Tags: bash, arguments, alias

I was wondering if there's any way to create an alias for a list of arguments.

Considering the following commands:

```
my_command --class_a_argument_one --class_a_argument_two --class_a_argument_three --class_a_argument_four

my_command --class_b_argument_one --class_b_argument_two --class_b_argument_three --class_b_argument_four

my_second_command --class_a_argument_one --class_a_argument_two --class_a_argument_three --class_a_argument_four
```

I want to create two different aliases for each list of arguments so that I could run these two commands using these:

```
my_command class_a_arguments
my_second_command class_a_arguments
my_command class_b_arguments
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called variables.

```
A="foo bar"
B="baz qoox"
my_command $A
your_command $B
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. But he seems to be a shell newbie, so it's good for him to encounter that problem if need be.

Answer (score 3):

Put your arguments in an array, and then invoke the command using that array.

```
$ arr1=(-e '\e[32mHello world\e[0m')
$ echo "${arr1[@]}"
Hello world
```